# in dom, what is functional difference between an html element and a fragment?

Tags: javascript, dom, html

have found fragments to be very useful in constructing dynamic html - like using a bag of html elements and the bag itself dissolving when put into place - very nice.

I had assumed the methods for html elements and fragments were the same, but I *think* this is incorrect.

it seems that fragments have node methods - `appendChild()` etc - but do not have more sophisticated html element methods, for example, `getElementsByTagName()`.

is this assessment correct?  or am I shooting myself in the foot in a new way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`DocumentFragment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3) extends the [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) interface and is defined as,

```
interface DocumentFragment : Node {
};
```

An [`HTMLElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58190037) extends from [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614), and its interface is defined as,

```
interface HTMLElement : Element {
    attribute DOMString id;
    attribute DOMString title;
    attribute DOMString lang;
    attribute DOMString dir;
    attribute DOMString className;
};
```

`Element` in-turn extends the `Node` interface. It contains the method `getElementsByTagName` among several others,

```
interface Element : Node {
    ...
    NodeList getElementsByTagName(in DOMString name);
    ..
};
```

So to answer your question in short, a document fragment and an html element both share the [node interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247).

Answer (score 1):

The `DocumentFragment` interface extends the [`Node` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247), thus providing methods to insert and clone elements, but *not* `getElementsByTagName()` and the like. These are to be found in the [`Document` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document) (which also extends `Node`).

Comment: *getElementsByTagName* is part of interface Element (see Anurag's post).

Comment: @RobG Yes, *and* [in `Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094).